Error on not refreshing the values in GUI from Tkinter
I am an absolute beginner for coding and I'm currently trying to design a turbine performance display using an Arduino Uno that will communicate the voltage reading using the input of pin A1.
This reading is then sent to Python and then the Python GUI is to display the readings for current etc based on the original serial input from Arduino. Based on the little I learnt, I did the simple coding from Arduino side and then designed a GUI using figma and converted it. My issue is, the data is only displayed as a sample for voltage and current  but I am unable to constantly refresh the data automatically as the current or voltage values change. What am I missing? When I tried doing a loop it bugs out the entire code.
This is the code I have been trying with the loop:
# Tkinter-Designer


from pathlib import Path

# from tkinter import *
# Explicit imports to satisfy Flake8
import serial

ser = serial.Serial ('COM4', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)

while 1:

arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
int(float(arduinoData))

voltageval = int(arduinoData)/204.6
currentval = int(arduinoData)/1.96



from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage


OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Users\haeyl\Downloads\tkinter\build\assets\frame0")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


window = Tk()

window.geometry("1280x720")
window.configure(bg = "#600000")


canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#600000",
    height = 720,
    width = 1280,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
canvas.create_rectangle(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1280.0,
    90.0,
    fill="#474646",
    outline="")

canvas.create_text(
    423.0,
    37.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="TURBINE PERFORMANCE DISPLAY",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 24 * -1)
)

image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    262.0,
    182.0,
    image=image_image_1
)

image_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_2.png"))
image_2 = canvas.create_image(
    909.0,
    182.0,
    image=image_image_2
)

image_image_3 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_3.png"))
image_3 = canvas.create_image(
    909.0,
    344.0,
    image=image_image_3
)

image_image_4 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_4.png"))
image_4 = canvas.create_image(
    262.0,
    348.0,
    image=image_image_4
)

image_image_5 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_5.png"))
image_5 = canvas.create_image(
    262.0,
    519.0,
    image=image_image_5
)

canvas.create_text(
    105.0,
    168.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="VOLTAGE",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    752.0,
    168.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="RPM",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    740.0,
    330.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="POWER",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    105.0,
    335.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="CURRENT",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    105.0,
    506.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="TORQUE",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    323.0,
    168.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text=(0 + voltageval),
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    970.0,
    168.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="rpmval",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    970.0,
    330.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="0 W ",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    323.0,
    335.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text=(0 + currentval),
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    323.0,
    506.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="0 N/M",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("Inter", 32 * -1)
)

image_image_6 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_6.png"))
image_6 = canvas.create_image(
    1132.0,
    563.0,
    image=image_image_6
)

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
button_1 = Button(
    image=button_image_1,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
)
button_1.place(
    x=709.0,
    y=476.0,
    width=264.0,
    height=108.0
)


    
     
    

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()




Since ser.readline() is a blocking function, it is better to execute serial port reading in a thread and transfer data to main thread using queue.  The main GUI application should read data from the queue constantly using .after().

I tried this. Thank you so much! . Its much better now. I used a pre existing format and am able to get a running GUI.. however, if i am to get separate readings from separate arduino pins, do i run different strings for each serial reading as it just only dumps the data into the serial monitor and py terminal?

I don't understand the question in your last comment.
